# Black screen saying missing operating system vista

Tags: boot

When I boot my laptop up I get a black screen and it says at the top:

> "missing operating system"

I cannot afford to take it to someone to fix it. What can I do?

Comment: Get a Windows CD and install an operating system. It's very hard to screw up. Give it a try and install an operating system.

Answer (score 1):

The boot loader could be corrupt. If you have the Vista disc you might be able to repair it. Here is a good article on how to do so.

https://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392